# Run EXE through BAT file

Tags: .net, batch-file

I have wrote such BAT file:

```
@echo off
set scriptDir=%~dp0
set synchronizerDir="C:\GPSM\Synchronizer"
rmdir /s /q %synchronizerDir%
xcopy "%scriptDir%Synchronizer" %synchronizerDir% /c /d /i /y /e
start "%synchronizerDir%\Synchronizer.exe"
```

In last code row I run my EXE file (console .NET application). But it ain't working. I get such screen:

[image]

But if I run my EXE manually - it works. Where my mistake? How can I run it through BAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this piece of code to close command:-

```
 start /d "path" %synchronizerDir%\Synchronizer.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

First START parameter in quotes is assumed to be the Window title; if you want to omit it, use an empty string:

```
start "" "%synchronizerDir%\Synchronizer.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

usually start likes a name for the action:

START "Running my File" "C:\PathTo\My.exe"